# php error data type mismatch in access

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$con = new COM('ADODB.Connection');
$con->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=C:\\cccc\\ccc\\LoginDatabase.accdb");

$name = $_POST["name"];  
$age = $_POST["age"];  
$username = $_POST["username"];  
$password = $_POST["password"];  

$sql1="INSERT INTO userinfo (name, username, [age], password) VALUES ('$name','$username', '$age', '$password')";

$rs = $con->Execute($sql1);
echo $result;

$response = array(); 
$response["success"] = true;   

echo json_encode($response); 
?> 

?>
```

I'm getting following error message

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:** Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers
> **Description:** [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.' in C:\android_connect\Register.php on line 15

age field is define as number in MS access 2010.

Comment: If `age` is a number, no need to quote it. Also, consider parameterizing your query which can be handled with ADO.